# svn status doesnt show me the list of modified files

Tags: svn, status

I checkedout some files inside dir using:

```
svn co  <dir>
```

After that  I used following command to replace some text in all java files inside this dir:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s/old/new/g"
```

Now, I fired this command:

```
svn status
```

It doesn't show the list of changed files. 
I can see the replacement in all java files but couldn't see the list of those files in svn  status command.

Please  help . Even svn commit not working.

Comment: Why didn't you do such a thing via your IDE?

Answer (score 6):

At a guess, your command will have also went through the files hidden inside the .svn directories. Potentially corrupting lots of things. Especially if your repository name had the text "old" in it. SVN will not like this!

What it will have definitely done is changed the "base" files inside .svn/text-base. So that as far as SVN is concerned nothing has changed (it compares the current directory to copies of the files in .svn to see what has changed).

Or, could be something else entirely.

Comment: I think this is exactly what might have happened . Replacing using sed really resulted in replacing the expression in base files in .svn directory as well  ..

Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 2):

The given find command is definitely wrong, cause you didn't prevent find from going into .svn folder which is wrong.

```
This results in creating a new checkout from scratch.
```

The following is comming close to what you need:

```
find . -type f -not -path "*\.svn*" -and -not -path "*/target*" -and -not -path "*/\.settings*" -name "*.java"
```

I would recommend to do this kind of things via IDE (Eclipse etc.)